# How to get location(affinity zone) or name cluster(fabric service)

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, affinity

I am currently using web api of fabric service.
Need to get the location(affinity zone) for fabric service cluster.
i.e to determine in which location the current cluster is located through code(c#)
in web API.
Or else i need the name of cluster where the web API is hosted.

In the webrole or cloud service it was possible using the 
https://management.core.windows.net/{0}/services/hostedservices

but i cannot find any way for cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but have a look at the ServiceEventSource that is created for a project. The ServiceMessage method shows you a lot of the information that is available from the service context.

```
ServiceMessage(
    service.Context.ServiceName.ToString(),
    service.Context.ServiceTypeName,
    service.Context.ReplicaId,
    service.Context.PartitionId,
    service.Context.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationName,
    service.Context.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationTypeName,
    service.Context.NodeContext.NodeName,
    finalMessage);
```

You could also look at the [FabricClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.fabric.fabricclient.aspx) class

Comment: No it did not helped

Answer (score 0):

After all the research i did it with

```
<Section Name="Affinity">
    <Parameter Name="Zone" Value="Eusa" />
</Section>
```

This is added in PackageRoot > Config > Setting